# Fortran subroutines with arrays

Tags: arrays, fortran, subroutine

I am having an issue with the subroutine in this program, which is at the end of the program. I am getting an error for the division of the arrays in the subroutine, which says "unclassifiable statement." Hope someone can help!

```
PROGRAM subroutine1
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER:: err, ierr, counter, y ,i ,j 
!INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE:: gamenum(:)
CHARACTER(30):: fname
REAL, ALLOCATABLE:: AB(:), H(:), TB(:), BA (:), SP(:)

100 Format (A)
200 Format (I2)
300 Format (F9.3)

! 1.Open file

WRITE(*,100)"Please enter a filename:"
READ(*,*) fname

OPEN (UNIT=10, FILE=fname, STATUS="OLD", ACTION="READ", IOSTAT=err)
IF(err.NE.0) STOP "An error occured when opening the file."

! 2.Count Lines

READ(10,*)

counter=0
DO
    READ(10,*,IOSTAT=ierr)
    IF(ierr .NE. 0) EXIT
    counter=counter+1
END DO

!WRITE(*,200) counter

! 3. allocate array

ALLOCATE(AB(counter)) 
ALLOCATE(H(counter))
ALLOCATE(TB(counter)) 
ALLOCATE(BA (counter)) 
ALLOCATE(SP(counter))

! 4. read in data

REWIND(10)

READ(10,*)

DO i=1,counter
    READ(10,*) AB(i), H(i), TB(i)   
END DO

REWIND(10)

! 5. Call subroutine

    CALL arraycalc(counter,AB,H,TB,BA,SP)

! 6. Write out
WRITE(*,100)"Game    AB       H       TB       BA       SP" 

DO i=1,counter
    WRITE(*,200,ADVANCE="NO") i
    WRITE(*,'(5F9.3)') AB(i), H(i), TB(i), BA(i), SP(i)
END DO

END PROGRAM subroutine1

!HERE IS THE PART WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE  

SUBROUTINE arraycalc(counter,AB,H,TB,BA,SP)
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, INTENT(IN)::counter
INTEGER::i
REAL,INTENT(INOUT)::AB,H,TB
REAL,INTENT(INOUT):: BA,SP

DO i=1,counter
    BA(i)=H(i)/AB(i)
END DO

DO i=1,counter
    SP(i)=TB(i)/AB(i)
END DO

END SUBROUTINE
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the subroutine, `AB`, `H`, `TB`, `BA`, and `SP` are not declared as arrays, so the statement that gives the error indeed makes no sense. They are scalars, so can not be indexed.

Comment: DIMENSION(:) should be added to their definition in the routine arraycalc

Comment: You will avoid other errors if you place your procedures into a module and "use" that module.   Not doing this is a frequent cause of Fortran questions here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @DaveP, procedures with assumed-shape arguments (i.e. `DIMENSION(:)`) must also have explicit interfaces in the calling code (or be module procedures).

Comment: @HristoIliev: Terminology note: it's not "either an explicit interface *or* in a module"; putting procedures in a module automatically provides an explicit interface. Another way is manually specifying the interface in an interface block.

Comment: @M.S.B.: Solid advice. I refrained from mentioning modules, because it wouldn't avoid the compilation error.

Comment: @eriktous, right, I meant "explicitly specified explicit interface". The correct term for such interface specification is _explicit specific interface_.

Comment: You just add the `(*)` to the array names you declared in the subroutine, i.e. `AB(*)` etc. This does not declare a dynamically allocated array, just a conformant one (of same size as passed from the caller). Alternatively, put explicit size `AB(counter)` ... had to dust-off my g95 setup :)